# Netbeans JSF when adding css or javascript error

Tags: javascript, html, css, jsf

I import my css file and javascript files in index.xhtml

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="resource/js/bag.js"></script>
```

My project works like this in http://localhost:8084/Proje1/ . But when i open http://localhost:8084/Proje1/faces/index.xhtml this url, doesn't work. It doesn't find css file and jquery files. How can i fix this. Thank you.

Comment: Checked the network tab of your browser for 404's This is not netbeans related bit servlet container (and not a specific one)

Answer (score 1):

Place your resource folder under WebContent, and replace your `<script>` import with this:

```
<script src="#{request.contextPath}/resource/js/bag.js"></script>
```